# man page only found after ran with root

Tags: linux, filesystems, root, redhat-enterprise-linux, manpages

When I try to run man page on my Red Hat as a normal user I get "No manual entry for zip"
If I change to root run: "man zip" and then I get the man page and afterwards I see the same man page as I did with root. Is there some kind of man page generation process taking place when I run it for the first time with root?

I have checked the /usr/share/man/man1/ there seem to be all the man pages for tools I usually use cp, ls, zip etc. I have also set $MANPATH envvar, but still no help.

Am I doing something wrong or the configuration on Red Hats differs from that of other Linux distros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to check whether then /usr/share/man/ permissions are correctly set. In my case the execute flag on all

> /usr/share/man/

folders was removed, except for root.

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/man/ # check if it has the x flag set for others
```

if x flag is not set, set it

```
$ chmod o+x /usr/share/man/*
```

of course you also want check if $MANPATH is correctly set as mention in an earlier answer.

Comment: +1. Only needed to add that execute permissions for others. Also, regarding that `MANPATH` variable, the manual says that the variable used only if it's been set. Sounds like it's not a requirement but can be set to override the default path.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your `MANPATH` is set incorrectly.

To test this, first try *unsetting* it:

```
$ unset MANPATH
$ man zip
```

If my guess is right, then you will `man` will use its default path and find the man page.

Also try comparing the output of `echo $MANPATH` as normal user vs root user.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it definitely helped to troubleshoot. Actually the problem was incorrect permission on man directories. There was no execute flag. After setting correct flag I could read mans. Thank you.

Comment: @7368616d696c If that wasn't the answer you used to fix your problem, then don't accept it - either have the answerer add that to his question or post it yourself.

Comment: As ekaj points out, you can add an answer to your own question. I think you have to wait a day or two to accept it. The benefit to explicitly adding your own answer is that if somebody in the future finds this question, your answer will be clearly marked as the solution and may help.